# Time taken to determine source of a wave

Tags: radiation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, frequency

I have a problem to solve. Suppose I have radiation coming at me from different sources, both with different frequencies, what would be the minimum time needed to find out where each source is coming from?

To solve this problem, I thought I could use the relation
$$
\text{time} = \lambda/c \qquad (\text{from } f=1/t)
$$
therefore $t = c/\nu c$ since ($\lambda = c/\nu$) and so for a frequency ($\nu$) the minimum time taken would be $1/\nu$.

However, I ran it by my professor and he says this is not the right approach. He says I have to use some type of interferometer to resolve my frequency between $n_2-n_1$, and then use Heisenberg's uncertainty principle to get my result.

I am so confused and I cant physically got o my professor at the moment for more clarity/detail and was hoping someone on this sub could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "radiation"? The minimum time to determine to the source of radiation -  I presume from $2$ sources - dependents on method and sources - which you have said nothing.  I don't understand how the frequency of the signal has anything to do with how long it takes you to locate the source. What do $n2-n1$ denote? I have no idea what problem is.

Comment: I have little to no information about this question from the professor which is frustrating, I only know that: I can use a point diffraction interferometer to measure and analyze the diffraction patterns of the two waves(radiation) as interference patterns are affected by the frequency of the wave. However, how that affects the minimum time I need to know where the source is coming from is confusing to me

Comment: Okay, looks like an optics problem. See if these references help - in the event you haven't already tried googling: "https://www.intechopen.com/books/optical-interferometry/point-diffraction-interferometry" and "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_diffraction_interferometer".

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is correct. Your argument doesn't make much sense at all (it is not really an argument at all, to be honest), so it's hard to pinpoint exactly where it is that you're going wrong, but it definitely does not apply here.

The minimal time to reliably determine the source of the wave in this situation is
$$
t_\mathrm{min} \approx \frac{1}{\Delta \nu} = \frac{1}{|\nu_1-\nu_2|},
$$
i.e., the reciprocal of the frequency difference between the two waves. This is basically the time it takes for the two waves to get significantly out of sync with each other, which then allows you to distinguish them.

Your argument gives you the *period* $T=1/\nu$ of the waves, but it does not tell you the *accuracy* to which you learn that period. Basically, if you only observe a single period of the waves, you get a very imprecise measurement of that period, compared to the case where you let the wave run for $N$ periods and divide by $N$, which gives you an uncertainty that's $N$ times smaller. If the two waves have frequencies that are very close together, they will have very similar periods, and you will need to measure them very accurately (i.e. over a large number of periods of oscillation) in order to distinguish the two.